# Correctly add a :not selector to these CSS styles

Tags: css

I have these three CSS styles:

```
.post-entry > blockquote {
    display: block;
    background-color: #eee;
    padding: 20px;
    border-left: 10px solid #0e65b6;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    font-size:1.3em;
}
.post-entry > blockquote:before {
    content:"\201C";
    font-size: 4em;
    line-height: 0.1em;
    margin-right: 0.25em;
    vertical-align: -0.4em;
}
.post-entry > blockquote p {
  display: inline;
}
```

I want to exclude them from appearing on `<blockquote class="tweet">`.

How do I correctly a "not" selector on each of them?

Thanks,

Chris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `blockquote` element has the class `tweet`, you would use `blockquote:not(.tweet)`.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/7knLw/)

```
.post-entry > blockquote:not(.tweet) {
    display: block;
    background-color: #eee;
    padding: 20px;
    border-left: 10px solid #0e65b6;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    font-size:1.3em;
}
.post-entry > blockquote:not(.tweet):before {
    content:"\201C";
    font-size: 4em;
    line-height: 0.1em;
    margin-right: 0.25em;
    vertical-align: -0.4em;
}
.post-entry > blockquote:not(.tweet) p {
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great. I was unsure of the exact position of the 
"not", particularly on the second one.